# Create virtual /dev/ttySx device

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, ports

I'm going to develop java application that works with serial port. I've tried to create serial port using socat, but I've created only pairs of /dev/pts/X.
I'm using kubuntu 14.04 LTS, kernel 4.1
Can anyone help me create virtual /dev/ttySx device that can be accessed without root permission?

I've got a solution!
https://askubuntu.com/questions/588800/setup-virtual-serial-ports-linux-null-modem-emulator-using-tty0tty/588806#588806
After this only make symlink any /dev/tntX to /dev/ttySX